# SSH Connection from server to another one without private key passphrase

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I'm trying to set up an ssh connection from ServerA to ServerB without password, and the ssh connection keeps asking me for the passphrase of my private key.

Here is my configuration:

**ServerA**

The `/home/user/.ssh` folder has a CHMOD: `rwx------`, and is owned by user:user

The files `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa` have a CHMOD: `-rw-------` and are owend by user:user

**ServerB**

I created a user serverA on the ServerB.
The folder `/home/serverA/.ssh` has a CHMOD: `drwx------` and is owned by serverA:serverA

The file `/home/serverA/.ssh/authorized_keys` contains the public key of the user on the ServerA, and has a CHMOD: `-rw-r-----`

In the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I added the following lines:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
```

However, when I am on ServerA and I try to type:
ssh ServerA@ServerB, it asks me for the passphrase of my private key. When I give it, I get connected.

Do you know how I could do to avoid typing the passphrase of ServerA every time?

Answer (score 1):

When you run ssh-keygen, you must have given the certificate a pass phrase. To not have to enter a pass phrase just press enter on that question to set an empty one when.

Comment: This will work for sure. However I'm not sure this is a good practice. When I try to connect to a server via SSH from my personal computer, I use my ssh key without any passphrase, and it works (even though I entered a passphrase when I did ssh-keygen).

Comment: You may have set up [ssh-agent](http://rabexc.org/posts/using-ssh-agent) but I am not sure how it would work with scripted connections

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ssh-agent`, which will "remember" your passphrase for specified time. In short:

```
eval `ssh-agent` # start ssh-agent
ssh-add /path/to/your.key # remeber the key
ssh ServerA@ServerB  # will not ask for a passphrase
```

for more information, check more questions about `ssh-agent` or its manual page.